# Rate of electrophilic bromination in aromatic nucleus

Tags: organic-chemistry

In Clayden,  the increased rate of electrophillic aromatic substitution is explained  by the stabilization of the intermediate through sigma conjugation. In Solomon & Frhyle, the same is explained through inductive effects.

Both  the factors  oppose each other in the following compounds: toluene, ethylbenzene, isopropylbenzene, and t-butylbenzene, respectively.

[image]

**My question:**

> What should be the order of electrophillic aromatic substitution for the above molecules ?

Comment: Can you cite the relevant chapters, page numbers, and the exact paragraph written in the books, to support your first paragraph? That will also give potential answer posters some additional insight into what the books might have meant. Thanks!

Comment: Hyperconjugation is more generally effective than inductive effects, I guess.

Comment: @Apoorv see this https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/88752/why-is-the-rate-of-reaction-of-polar-eas-favored-by-inductive-effects-and-the-ra

Comment: I  was thinking too simplistically.